Problema de transcripcion al automatizar posts de Facebook
estoy intentando automatizar posts de facebook para varias paginas que NO son mias, es decir que el GRAPH API De facebook no sirve para este caso. Estoy utilizando python + selenium para extraer usuario + contraseña, url de grupos y texto de archivos .txt y usarlos en el codigo para iniciar sesion, entrar al grupo que el usuario agregue al txt, abrir el textbox de posts, escribir, agregar imagen y subirlo.
El problema, al momento de pasar el texto del codigo a Facebook solamente se pasa la primera letra de cada renglón, es decir que si mi texto dice:
Hola
Todo
Bien?
se pasa como
H
T
B
Intente hacerlo de varias formas, con la funcion send_keys() y el texto completo, usar un bucle if con la misma funcion send_keys(), simular un CTRL + V con varias librerias y aun asi nada. La unica que funciono para poner el texto completo fue el bucle if, pero su lentitud hace inutil al codigo.
Tambien intente agregar imagenes al post pero no pude conseguirlo, intente con el send_keys() y tambien simulando el CTRL + V.
Si alguno tiene idea de como solucionarlo se agradece, hace mucho tiempo no toco nada de programación y estoy oxidado
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

print("navegador")
#abre navegador
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=profile)
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
browser.maximize_window()

print("datos")
#carga datos
arch3 = open("datos.txt", "r")
user = []

arch2 = open("grupos.txt", 'r')
list = []

for i in arch2.readlines():
    list.append(i)
    arch2.close()

for i in arch3.readlines():
    user.append(i)
arch3.close()

print("login")
#login
login = browser.find_element(By.ID, "email")
login.send_keys(user[0])

p = browser.find_element(By.ID, "pass")
p.send_keys(user[1])
time.sleep(5)
#p.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    boton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with (@id, 'u_0_5_')]")
    boton.click()
    time.sleep(10)
except:
    print("No Login")
    time.sleep(25000)

print("grupo")
#grupo
for i in list:
    grupos = 0
    browser.get(i)

    print("post")
    #Post
    time.sleep(20)
    post = WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div")))
    post.click()


    print("post 1.1")
    time.sleep(20)
    post2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]")))
    post2.click()

    post2.send_keys("Hello World")

    time.sleep(25000)

los time.sleep estan ahi para los tiempos de carga que mi PC de bajo performance le cuesta y los prints() son para seguir la ejecucion de codigo en la terminal al mismo tiempo que de forma visual
